# Insert custom ID into wp_get_attachment_link

Tags: attachments, urls

I'm working on this function of WordPress.

```
function wp_get_attachment_link( $id = 0, $size = 'thumbnail', $permalink = false, $icon = false, $text = false ) {
    $id = intval( $id );
    $_post = get_post( $id );

    if ( empty( $_post ) || ( 'attachment' != $_post->post_type ) || ! $url = wp_get_attachment_url( $_post->ID ) )
        return __( 'Missing Attachment' );

    if ( $permalink )
        $url = get_attachment_link( $_post->ID );

    $post_title = esc_attr( $_post->post_title );

    if ( $text )
        $link_text = $text;
    elseif ( $size && 'none' != $size )
        $link_text = wp_get_attachment_image( $id, $size, $icon );
    else
        $link_text = '';

    if ( trim( $link_text ) == '' )
        $link_text = $_post->post_title;

    return apply_filters( 'wp_get_attachment_link', "<a href='$url' title='$post_title'>$link_text</a>", $id, $size, $permalink, $icon, $text );
}
```

And I want to modify this line:

```
return apply_filters( 'wp_get_attachment_link', "<a href='$url' title='$post_title'>$link_text</a>", $id, $size, $permalink, $icon, $text );
```

I want that link can output like this:

```
<a href='$url' title='$post_title' id='**my_wish_attachment_ID**'>$link_text</a>
```

Because, default it print out like this:

```
<a href='http://link-to-image' title='post-title-example'><img src="http://link-to-thumbnail.png" class="attachment-thumbnail" alt="post-title-example" /></a>
```

I want it print out like this:

```
<a href='http://link-to-image' title='post-title-example' id='post-title-example'><img src="http://link-to-thumbnail.png" class="attachment-thumbnail" alt="post-title-example" /></a>
```

My wished attachment ID could be the same with 'post-title-example'.

I have tried many ways and searched Google a lot. But it doesn't work.

Can you help me? Thank you.

Comment: What ways have you tried?

Comment: I tried this way:

`add_filter('wp_get_attachment_link', 'add_id_into_link');
function add_id_into_link($link) {
 global $post;
 return str_replace('<a href', '<a id="'. $attachment_ID .'" href', $link);
}`

Comment: it does not work with `$post_ID` or `$post_title` or `$_post->post_title` also :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to supply a argument count when adding the filter callback, and add the arguments you are expecting to receive to your callback function. Looking at the `wp_get_attachment_link` source you can tell that 6 arguments is supplied when applying the filters (the link markup and `$id, $size, $permalink, $icon, $text`). Here's how you could would do just that:

```
add_filter('wp_get_attachment_link', 'add_id_into_link', 10, 6);
function add_id_into_link($link, $id = null, $size = null, $permalink = null, $icon = null, $text = null) {
    return str_replace('<a href', '<a id="'. $id .'" href', $link);
}
```

Comment: hello, thank you very much. But your code just print out the number of ID, I need it like `post_title` so I take a look and follow your advice, here is my code:

`add_filter('wp_get_attachment_link', 'add_id_into_link', 10, 6);
function add_id_into_link($link, $id = null, $size = null, $permalink = null, $icon = null, $text = null) {
 $id = intval( $id );
 $_post = get_post( $id );
 $post_title = esc_attr( $_post->post_title );
    return str_replace('<a href', '<a id="'. $post_title .'" href', $link);
} `

And it works! Is it ok right now?

Comment: I don't know how to add code in beautiful way like you @Simon

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't quite understand what data you wanted in the id-attribute, but you seem to have solved that just fine. Happy to help! Regarding code formatting I think it's not just possible to use indentation and syntax highlight in comments, only in questions/answers.